# javascript/jquery .animate() hue-rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, hue

can you use .animate() to animate hue-rotation?
if not is there a list of which properties can be animated in this function. This link : https://api.jquery.com/animate implys that .animate() is a jQuery function only, but it is working on my project without using jQuery. has this been absorbed into javascript & also, how do you manipulate css hue-rotate through javascript. i cannot find many references to this either on google or stack exchange.

I have tried many combinations of hueRotate, making it an object, json and creating string literals via `` but none of them seem to work.

```
    Info.style.filter = ('hueRotate:240deg;');
    Info.style.filter = `hue-rotate(240deg);`
    Info.style.filter = {(hue-rotate(240deg)};
    Info.style.filter.hueRotate = "240deg";
```

I have literally tried dozens of combinations both inside & outside of
.animate & requestAnimationFrame but none of them are working.
its probably really simple.

Comment: `Info.style.filter = 'hue-rotate(240deg);'`

Comment: doesn't do anything... just stays the same.

Comment: remove the `;` ..

Comment: yea, that worked. Thank you so much i've been trying this for hours..... :). have a cookie

Comment: is this possible in .animate()?

Comment: Another question i have that doesn't merit an intirely new question is that sublime text 3 does not recognise hue-rotate when it is included in a transition statement but it recognises opacity. should transition just be on filter or is transition:hue-rotate x'ms ease-in x'ms; Ok syntax it doesn't seem to work & is not highlighting properly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes [web animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) can animate filters too, like any animatable CSS properties. You simply need to specify the initial value and the final one.

```js
document.getElementById("box").animate(
  {
    filter: ['hue-rotate(0deg)', 'hue-rotate(360deg)']
  },
  {
    duration: 2500,
    iterations: Infinity
  }
);
```

```css
#box {
  background: linear-gradient( to right, purple, orange); 
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Well it could actually be written in [many different syntaxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Keyframe_Formats)...